# jQuery - on image hover add class to another element with the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I'm struggling with jQuery speakers image grid. I would like that on image hover text in yellow box changed to this hovered speaker data (they have the same class). So for example when I hover over first black box (image) I should see speaker 1 data (and by default first one is visible), then on second black box (image) hover I should see speaker 2 data etc. The speaker image and speaker data `div`'s has the same class like `.speaker-1`, `.speaker-2`, `.speaker-3`... and I want add class `.active` to then change specific text visibility.

My initial code is here: https://jsfiddle.net/f9vo76cn/1/, but it looks like a lot of unnecessary classes repetition. I will be very grateful for your help.

HTML

```
<div class="speakers-container">
  <div class="speaker-image speaker-1"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="photo"></div>
  <div class="speaker-information">
    <div class="speaker-info speaker-1 active">
      <p class="name">Speaker 1 Name and Surname</p>
      <p class="company">Speaker 1 Company</p>
    </div>
        <div class="speaker-info speaker-2">
      <p class="name">Speaker 2 Name and Surname</p>
      <p class="company">Speaker 2 Company</p>
    </div>
        <div class="speaker-info speaker-3">
      <p class="name">Speaker 3 Name and Surname</p>
      <p class="company">Speaker 3 Company</p>
    </div>
        <div class="speaker-info speaker-4">
      <p class="name">Speaker 4 Name and Surname</p>
      <p class="company">Speaker 4 Company</p>
    </div>
    <div class="speaker-info speaker-5">
      <p class="name">Speaker 5 Name and Surname</p>
      <p class="company">Speaker 5 Company</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="speaker-image speaker-2"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="photo"></div>
  <div class="speaker-image speaker-3"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="photo"></div>
  <div class="speaker-image speaker-4"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="photo"></div>
  <div class="speaker-image speaker-5"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="photo"></div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(".speaker-2").hover(
  function() {
    $('.speaker-2').addClass('active');
    $('.speaker-1').removeClass('active');
  },
  function() {
    $('.speaker-1').addClass('active');
    $('.speaker-2').removeClass('active');
  }
);
```

[image: toggle class on hover]

Comment: all code with html and my jQuery is in my jsfiddle link - https://jsfiddle.net/f9vo76cn/1/

Comment: Why are you handling the hover event just on one of the elements - `.speaker-2`?

Comment: Beacuse I am searching for better way than adding every speaker-1, speaker-2, speaker-3 etc.

Comment: You might need to expand on this one, but I guess that's what you're after? `$(".speaker-info").on("hover", function () { $(".speaker-info").removeClass("active"); $(this).addClass("active"); });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of giving the elements a class `speaker-*`, I gave them an data-attribute, `data-speaker="speaker-*"`.
Then you can use that in your jQuery. I've added comments to explain what happens.

```js
$('.speaker-image').on('mouseenter', function(){
  var speaker = $(this).data('speaker'); /* get the speaker, based on the data attribute (data-speaker) */
  $('.speaker-info').removeClass('active'); /* remove the active class of all .speaker-info divs */
  $('.'+speaker).addClass('active'); /* add the active class to the right div */
})
```

```css
.speakers-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  gap: 35px;
}

.speakers-container img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.speaker-information {
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 10px;
}

.speaker-info {
  display: none;
}

.speaker-info.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="speakers-container">
  <div class="speaker-image" data-speaker="speaker-1"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="photo"></div>
  <div class="speaker-information">
    <div class="speaker-info speaker-1 active">
      <p class="name">Speaker 1 Name and Surname</p>
      <p class="company">Speaker 1 Company</p>
    </div>
    <div class="speaker-info speaker-2">
      <p class="name">Speaker 2 Name and Surname</p>
      <p class="company">Speaker 2 Company</p>
    </div>
    <div class="speaker-info speaker-3">
      <p class="name">Speaker 3 Name and Surname</p>
      <p class="company">Speaker 3 Company</p>
    </div>
    <div class="speaker-info speaker-4">
      <p class="name">Speaker 4 Name and Surname</p>
      <p class="company">Speaker 4 Company</p>
    </div>
    <div class="speaker-info speaker-5">
      <p class="name">Speaker 5 Name and Surname</p>
      <p class="company">Speaker 5 Company</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="speaker-image" data-speaker="speaker-2"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="photo"></div>
  <div class="speaker-image" data-speaker="speaker-3"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="photo"></div>
  <div class="speaker-image" data-speaker="speaker-4"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="photo"></div>
  <div class="speaker-image" data-speaker="speaker-5"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="photo"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: A similar option is to add the same `data-speaker` to both elements,then use `$("[data-speaker=" + speaker + "]")`.  No real difference, just an alternative method to link them.

Comment: Thank you very much! It's working and is a better way, you're right.

Comment: Why don't you target directly ```class="speaker-image speaker-X"```?

Comment: I need a regex to determine the `speaker-X` value. With `data-*` attribute works easier for me